# How to view file date of result of find command in bash

Tags: bash, find, ls

I use a find command to find some kinds of files in bash. Everything goes fine unlness the result that is shown to me just contains the file name but not the (last modification) date of file. I tried to pipe it into ls or ls -ltr but it just does not show the filedate column in result, also I tried this:

```
ls -ltr | find . -ctime 1
```

but actually I didn't work.
Can you please guide me how can I view the filedate of files returned by a find command?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need either `xargs` or `-exec` for this:

```
find . -ctime 1 -exec ls -l {} \;

find . -ctime 1 | xargs ls -l
```

(The first executes `ls` on every found file individually, the second bunches them up into one ore more big `ls` invocations, so that they may be formatted slightly better.)

Comment: Thank you. It is completely true.

Comment: @Farshid: `-mtime` is the modification time.

Answer (score 8):

If all you want is to display an ls like output you can use the `-ls` option of find:

```
$ find . -name resolv.conf -ls
1048592    8 -rw-r--r--   1 root     root          126 Dec  9 10:12 ./resolv.conf
```

If you want only the timestamp you'll need to look at the `-printf` option

```
$ find . -name resolv.conf -printf "%a\n"
Mon May 21 09:15:24 2012
```

Comment: To sort by date, add " | sort -n " to the end.  Details: https://superuser.com/a/546900/299967 (Still works a decade later)

Answer (score 2):

```
find . -ctime 1 -printf '%t\t%p\n'
```

prints the datetime and file path, separated by a [␉ character](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2409/index.htm).